# Echo Submit Button in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to echo a submit form in my php code:

I am trying the following:

```
// Display results
foreach ($media->data as $data) {
echo "<a href=\"{$data->link}\"</a>";
echo "<h4>Photo by: {$data->user->username}</h6>";
echo $pictureImage = "<img src=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\">";
echo "<h5>Like Count for Photo: {$data->likes->count}</h5>";
echo "<form>";
echo "<form action='tag.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

}
```

Then:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "hello";
}
```

This doesn't seem to echo "hello";

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` :P

Comment: You forgot to close a parenthesis in your `if` statement.

Comment: I would suggest to stop using Notepad as your [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments) and choose one that would have saved you time writing this question.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a closing parenthesis:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                          ^
                          Here
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a value on the input tag. Change it to:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Active">';
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                          ^
 echo "hello";
}
```

you missed a parenthesis.

**Edit:** Also it should be:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
```

Else $_POST['submit'] will not get set.

Comment: @asg then your `submit` variable contains nothing.

Comment: @JeffNoel with that form, `$_POST['submit']` should return 'Submit' I believe

Comment: @asg is that your actual code? I don't the any obvious error.

Comment: @TobSpr I'm checking it right now. I doubt the `input[type="submit"]` elements are sent to the server. I'll edit this post in a few seconds. **Edit --> You are right:** `array (size=1)
  'submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)` That might be hell of a good way to check which form sent the data !

Comment: Yeah they are sent. I know that many sites check it, to check wheter it was actual their form, because most devs don't know it.

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to make it so that when the submit button is pressed it echo's hello.

Comment: @asg Why don't you do it in JavaScript then?

Comment: @Jeff I think later he will pass form data